# Android - is it be possible to use Different Pattern in API in retrofit 2?

Tags: php, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I have this type of API

```
www.abcd.com/users.php?request=saveuser
```

Can we use this type API into retrofit and send the data to PHP instead of using below given API

```
www.abcd.com/users.php?name="name"&password="P@ssword"
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what exactly you mean? The quotation marks?

Comment: When we use retrofit
 @GET("/eapp/result.php")
Call<Data> getResults(@Query("cont_id") Integer cId);
which will use API format like this /eapp/result.php?cont_id=1

Comment: Can you point out what the difference between the two examples you gave is? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: yes you can ,you can use matrix param, query param ,path param , and  beans param(json and xml ),form body for more info RTFM of retrofit document and rest api design documentation

Comment: I want to send userdata that is name and password from android to php using this type of API www.abcd.com/users.php?request=saveuser

Comment: send name and password as form body and query param as saveuser

Comment: if want to fetch users data from API www.abcd.com/request=getusers
by passing user_id . what retrofit format need to be written?

Comment: Can you give example on those ? or  can you please share me the link?

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of requests, among them are `GET` and `POST`. You can use those in Retrofit accordingly.

```
interface MyApiService {

    @POST("users.php")
    fun getUsers(@Query("request") requestMethod: String = "getusers", @Body body: MyRequest): Call<MyResponseModel>

}
```

Where `MyRequestModel` and `MyResponseModel` are the data models you want to use.

Read more about requests [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

Comment: @GET("users.php") can be used by sending userid to it or need to use post only ?